# text-shadow on IE doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I use this in my CSS:

```
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
```

Text on IE:
[image: IE]

Text on Firefox:[image: Firefox]

and here [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eX7x8/1/)

How can I let it work on IE too? thanks.

Comment: Hm i see shadow in my IE. WHat version you use?

Comment: [It seems](http://jsfiddle.net/eX7x8/3/show/) not to work in IE9.

Comment: Text-shadow is supported in Internet Explorer 10 upwards (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673564(v=vs.85).aspx and http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow).

Comment: @pwdst IE9 doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

USE MS-Filter..

```
p.shadowed {
  text-shadow: #0000ff 0px 0px 3px; /* Modern browsers */
  filter: glow(color=#0000ff,strength=3); /* IE */
  //alternative
  //filter: dropshadow(color=#ffff00,offX=5,offY=5);
}
```

Comment: Can I have JSfiddle, cause i got black color on input background field.

Comment: Sure. BTW check this method as an alternative: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(direction=135,strength=2,color=ff0000);

Comment: Also checking here can be useful: http://heygrady.com/blog/2011/03/10/css-text-shadows-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Has someone tested these stupid -ms-filters on the real Exploiter 9/8/7 ?

Comment: Microsoft have made available free virtual machines to test previous versions of Internet Explorer in (as you will know it is not possible to have multiple versions installed on the same computer) and are also offered a free three month subscription to browser stack which would allow remote testing. This could make testing easier. http://www.modern.ie/en-US

Comment: @Stano: Why are you voting down for me, while I'm trying to help Moath? I'm not fallen in love with these crazy IE commands and filters but they are formally promoted by MS as their solution for making these types of effects/transitions and I'm just helping the asker for resolving his problem.

Comment: No Farshid, I didn't downvote your answer, I don't see any reason for downvoting here. I only wrote here one comment, question. Can you please recommend the correct filter among those three ones? (glow, dropshadow or DXImageTransform? And also there existed [-ms prefixes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I don't know nothing about it. Just your answer provides three alternatives, but which one works? Or what is the correct IE9/8/7 compatible combination, solution?